# ERROR in ./src/components/BasicList.js Module build failed: SyntaxError: Decorators are not officially supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I am getting

```
ERROR in ./src/components/BasicList.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Decorators are not officially supported yet in 6.x pending a proposal update.
However, if you need to use them you can install the legacy decorators transform with:

npm install babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy --save-dev

and add the following line to your .babelrc file:

{
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

because of

```
import React from 'react';
// http://glortho.github.io/react-keydown/example/index.html
import keydown from 'react-keydown';

import {Grid, Row, Column} from 'react-cellblock';

import MyComponent from '../utils/MyComponent';

@keydown
export default class BasicList extends MyComponent {
```

I have installed the package as asked multiple times and still confused as to why it won't work.

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]

}
```

packages:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-cellblock": "^3.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-keydown": "^1.7.3",
    "react-redux": "4.3.0",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "requests": "^0.1.7",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

All the answers about this say to do what I already did. I keep restarting npm server to no avail.

Comment: do you have any another plugins inside your .babelrc file?

Comment: my bablerc is above, it only has 1 plugin. I just posted webpack config if that may help. ty

Comment: you can actually remove the query from inside of loaders, since you already have a babelrc file now.

Comment: beautiful, please make as formal answer and take the points. ty Vivek

Comment: posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as it appears is with your webpack.config.js file.
The correct config file should be without the key query inside the loaders, since all those have been already specified inside your .babelrc file.

The updated webpack.config.js file should be:-

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```